# Continuity for integers valued functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{Z}$ is continuous, then $f$ is constant function.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/313904/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/505472/42969

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $:$ Continuous image of a connected set is connected. What are the connected subsets of $\Bbb Z$? Are they not the singletons?